# Web scraping using Python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, containers, text-mining

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
my_url="http://www.mouthshut.com/mobile-operators/Reliance-Jio-reviews-925812061"

uClient=uReq(my_url)

page_html=uClient.read()

page_soup=soup(page_html,"html.parser")

containers=page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"row review-article"})
print(len(containers))
print(containers[0].a)
```

I want to get the link of profile (Chitanverma in the given picture) as my output but I get the link of Reliance Jio services as my output.

[image: picture[1]]

I would be grateful if someone help me correct my code to get the expected output and also explain why I am getting the link of Reliance Jio services as my output.

My intention is to scrape the names of the profile from the webpage http://www.mouthshut.com/mobile-operators/Reliance-Jio-reviews-925812061.

Comment: Where is it failing? What's the trouble here?

Comment: As I said in the question, I am getting the link of reliance jio services as my output rather than the link of profile names of those who have commented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you have to rely on any browser simulator to grab the dynamically generated content. Selenium can be an option to go with. Try the below example if you have installed selenium in your machine already.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium  import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.mouthshut.com/mobile-operators/Reliance-Jio-reviews-925812061')
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")
for link in soup.select(".profile"):
    try:
        profile = link.select("p:nth-of-type(1) a")[0]
    except:pass      
    print(profile.text, profile['href'])

driver.quit()
```

Partial output:

```
chintanverma http://www.mouthshut.com/chintanverma
ganeshgauttam http://www.mouthshut.com/ganeshgauttam
viratvenkat1 http://www.mouthshut.com/viratvenkat1
ms37872 http://www.mouthshut.com/ms37872
bibekdas http://www.mouthshut.com/bibekdas
```

Comment: Can you help me editing the code which you have shared by modifying the code for using Mozilla simulator rather than chrome ?

Comment: Thanks for the code. It worked. I used Firefox webdriver instead of chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Correct selector for div with user data is:

```
containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "profile"})
first_container = containers[0]
```

But this fragment of DOM is rendered by call of javascript method getuserprofile, so you can't retrieve it using beatifulsoup, because it returns:

```
<div class="col-2 profile" id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderFooter_ContentPlaceHolderBody_rptreviews_ctl00_divProfile"><script> 

getuserprofile(1318536,8393808,0,1,0,'','ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderFooter_ContentPlaceHolderBody_rptreviews_ctl00_divProfile',3,'ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderFooter_ContentPlaceHolderBody_rptreviews_ctl00_spnview','ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderFooter_ContentPlaceHolderBody_rptreviews_ctl00_smdatetime')
</script></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for giving me the reason for why I haven't got my output.